# Cannot get params from httpRequest

Tags: java, http, servlets, apache-httpclient-4.x

I want to transfer a string from the client to a web server.

The Client Code:

```
String uriString = "http://128.128.4.120:8080/GCMService/GCMBroadcast";
URI uri = null;
try {
    uri = new URI(uriString);
} catch (URISyntaxException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPut httpPut = null;
if(uri!=null)
httpPut = new HttpPut(uri);
HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
params.setParameter("mymsg", "HELLO SERVER");
httpClient.setParams(params);
HttpResponse resp = httpClient.execute(httpPut);
```

The Server Code:

```
@Override
protected void doPut(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
throws ServletException, IOException {      
    System.out.println(req.getParameter("mymsg"));

}
```

The console of server prints "null", which I hope should be "HELLO SERVER", each time the client requests the httpPut. How is this caused and how can I solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String uriString = "http://128.128.4.120:8080/GCMService/GCMBroadcast";
URIBuilder uriBuilder = new URIBuilder(uriString);
uriBuilder.addParameter("mymsg", "HELLO SERVER");
DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPut httpPut = new HttpPut(uriBuilder.build());
HttpResponse resp = httpClient.execute(httpPut);
```

Comment: thank you for your reply. I didn't test your code yet. I'm curious what exactly is wrong in my code. I wanna know it so I can have better understanding about HTTPComponents.

Comment: From HTTP Components javadoc: "HttpParams interface represents a collection of immutable values that define a runtime behavior of a component". Obviously, they're not the same as parameters which your server-side component receives in req.getParameter(...)